# Project time series from previous time series examples and characteristics

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval, projection

Say I want to open a shop but first I want to project the likely sales in the first 5 years to see if it is a viable option.

I have data pertaining to 100s of other start ups, including their success in the first 5 years measured as sales, location, average income of surrounding households, median age, local population, etc.

What would be the best method of projecting the sales of the shop I want to open? One approach would be to predict sales in year 1, then separate model for year 2, but I would like to avoid building 5 different models.

Open to all options. Although would be interested in how to tackle in a Bayesian approach or approaches that can produce prediction intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any agreement on the "best" way to do this. Predictions for future results are worse further in the future IMHO (but I am not an expert). Structural breaks occur that change the results over time. The simplest way is to plot a univariate time series of success rate using say exponential smoothing or ARIMA (the former is far easier than the later to do). The experts I have read, very few of the total experts of course, felt univariate methods like this were more accurate at predicting the DV than multivariate models where you have predictors. You won't be able to tell from this if a predictor had an impact of course. If you are new to time series I would try exponential smoothing if you want likely future results.

Comment: I would be interested in reading any resources you have pertaining to univariate approaches being better than a multivariate approach, as I was really aiming for answers surrounding the multivariate angle.

Comment: I will look, but understand my sources for this are going to be a relatively small group of the total experts in the field and its going to be merely their opinion based on their own expertise as far as I know. If there is a consensus on this I don't know what it is. If you are lucky some of the time series experts on this board (of which I am not one) such as Irishstats or Hyndman will see this and address it. I am just quoting people I read. One place to start is the M contests. It will be a few days before I have time to address this.